# Best practice to implement stores

Tags: users, organic-groups, nodes

I want to allow my site users to create stores,, in which each store can contain content.
so the store is basically a page which contain specific content.

what's the best way to implement this in Drupal?

Comment: Do you need each store to have credit card checkout?

Answer (score 1):

We used OG extensively in many sites with stores that are auto-created when a user registers.  You can check out one of them here - www.craftsaid.com - each "store" is an OG.  We also did the same thing on Bandromeda.com.

Install Organic Groups Module - http://drupal.org/project/og
Install Rules Module - http://drupal.org/project/rules

After you have created a content type for your Group type (this can be anything you want it to be - if you're not familiar with OG it is an incredibly powerful platform that allows users to create groups to which other members may subscribe - essentially you create one content type as the "group" type itself and then any other content type can be set as "group content" that may be added to a given group) go to /admin/workflow/rules and add a rule for Event = After saving a new user account with an Action = Create a new entity with parameters of Entity type: Node, Content type: Your Group Content Type, Title: [use tokens to create your title configuration]

This will auto-create a Group upon registration.  Otherwise you could simply create a link to node/add/store (or whatever your group content type is) from wherever makes the most sense in your site.

That is a very basic explanation - there are probably 50 ways you could implement this to accommodate your general description of your need.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If each store is just a page, with no checkout process, then you could

1. Create a "Product" content type, add required [fields](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui)
2. Configure [role and permission](http://drupal.org/node/22275) to allow adding product node
3. Create a [View](http://drupal.org/project/views) listing products for a particular store ( by product author(s) )

Alternatively, you could look at a commerce solution such as [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) or [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart), but that may be overkill in this situation when a core solution + Views may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module. Also here is a link to all the [projects](http://drupal.org/node/206712) associated with this module. Looks like there used to be a "store" feature, but that was back with Drupal 4.x. However if the store only holds pieces of content, not actual sales, then OG does a great job of managing multiple "stores" within the site.